# Django populate() isn't reentrant on multilanguage setup with different domains

Tags: django, multilingual

I run a Django==1.10.4 website with 4 different languages. Each of them has there own domain. Only 2 or 3 of them are working at the same time. One or more is failing with this error:

This is the error which appears after I kill my wsgi processes and access the page the first time:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=8416): Target WSGI script '/var/www/user324/htdocs/ukmypagecom/app.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
 mod_wsgi (pid=8416): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/user324/htdocs/ukmypagecom/app.wsgi'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/var/www/user324/htdocs/ukmypagecom/app.wsgi", line 11, in <module>
     application = django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()
   File "/var/www/user324/priv/venv/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
   File "/var/www/user324/priv/venv/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
   File "/var/www/user324/priv/venv/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
     app_config.import_models(all_models)
   File "/var/www/user324/priv/venv/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 199, in import_models
     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
     __import__(name)
   File "/var/www/user324/priv/venv/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
     from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
   File "/var/www/user324/priv/venv/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
     class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
   File "/var/www/user324/priv/venv/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 119, in __new__
     new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
   File "/var/www/user324/priv/venv/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 316, in add_to_class
     value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
   File "/var/www/user324/priv/venv/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
     self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
   File "/var/www/user324/priv/venv/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
     return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
   File "/var/www/user324/priv/venv/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
     backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
   File "/var/www/user324/priv/venv/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 134, in load_backend
     raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
 ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.mysql' isn't an available database backend.
 Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
     'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
 Error was: cannot import name GEOSException
```

After each page reload I get only this error:

```
 mod_wsgi (pid=8416): Target WSGI script '/var/www/user324/htdocs/ukmypagecom/app.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
 mod_wsgi (pid=8416): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/user324/htdocs/ukmypagecom/app.wsgi'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/var/www/user324/htdocs/ukmypagecom/app.wsgi", line 11, in <module>
     application = django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()
   File "/var/www/user324/priv/venv/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
   File "/var/www/user324/priv/venv/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
   File "/var/www/user324/priv/venv/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
 RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

This is how my settings file looks for each domain.

```
#settings_en.py
from base_settings import *

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', '.example.com' ]
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-GB'
ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.base_urls'
SITE_ID = 18

#settings_pl.py
from base_settings import *

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', '.example.com' ]
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pl-PL'
ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.base_urls'
SITE_ID = 19

#settings_xx.py
...
```

And this is how my app.wsgi looks like for each Domain

```
#english version

#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os

sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/user324/priv/venv/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages') #virtualenv
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/user324/priv/mysourcecode') #sourcecode

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings_en'

import django.core.wsgi
application = django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()


#polish version
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os

sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/user324/priv/venv/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/user324/priv/mysourcecode')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings_pl'

import django.core.wsgi
application = django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()
```

Any idea what is going wrong here?

After I restart my wsgi processes some domains are working some are not working. Every domain is accessing the same sourcecode and same database. So I think there is not a problem with the source code, because those sites which run directly doesn't have any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look like a Django problem, but a misconfiguration of mod_wsgi -- it looks like your applications may be running in the same interpreter and conflicting.

How is your Apache/mod_wsgi configured? Of special interest is that [daemon mode](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/processes-and-threading.html#the-mod-wsgi-daemon-processes) should be turned on and the daemon separate for each site. ([See that directive's docs.](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html))

Also, I'd suggest looking into serving your app with something else than Apache/mod_wsgi -- Nginx + uWSGI is my weapon of choice.

Comment: You've been right. I run for each site a different daemon and everything is running fine again. Thank You!